# Driving simulation:overtaking, im having an issue with lane changing in my netlogo

Tags: netlogo

In my project i am writing a semi-autonomous car simulation, as a beginner i have used a basic version of a driving simulation and aiming to expand it, whist expanding the coding i was trying to mimic lane centring, so have made each lane or a road three patches thick, in doing so i'm struggling to make cars overtake correctly now.

it was defined that the car should occupy all three of the patches as not to have two cars in one lane, but in coding this the car in the inner lane that should overtake now will only stay behind. i want the inner lane to overtake.

```
to control-speed01
let in-lane (patch-set patch-ahead 3 patch-left-and-ahead 26 2 patch-right-
and-ahead 26 2 )
let car-ahead one-of cars-on in-lane

 ifelse car-ahead = nobody  [
ifelse speed < maxSpeed [set speed speed + acceleration] [set speed speed - 
deceleration]
 ]
 [
ifelse [speed] of car-ahead = 0 [set speed 0] [
  ifelse [speed] of car-ahead >= maxSpeed [
    set speed maxSpeed
    set speed speed - deceleration
  ] [
 ; try to overtake
  ifelse [meaning] of patch-left-and-ahead 26 2 = meaning and not any? 
turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 26 2 and [meaning] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 != "crossroad"
  and meaning != "crossing" and [meaning] of patch-left-and-ahead 180 1.3 != "crossing" and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 169 3
  and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 45 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 135 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 23 2
  and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 157 2 and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 12 3 and [meaning] of patch-ahead 1 != "crossing" [move-to patch-left-and-ahead 90 1] [


    ifelse [meaning] of patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 = meaning and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 90 14 and [meaning] of patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 != "crossroad"
    and meaning != "crossing" and [meaning] of patch-right-and-ahead 180 1.3 != "crossing" and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 12 3
    and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 45 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 135 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 23 2
    and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 157 2 and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 169 3 and [meaning] of patch-ahead 1 != "crossing"[move-to patch-right-and-ahead 90 1] [
      set speed [speed] of car-ahead
      set speed speed - deceleration]
  ][enter image description here][1]
  ]
 ]
 ]
 end
```

in the coding is a section about dealing with pedestrian crossings but for simplicity i have removed people for now.

i think i need to have different angles in the first line of "try to overtake". but i'm not sure. i stress that i am a beginner, if i can make the question clearer please say.